# Calculating vector lengths within my loop

Tags: matlab

The code is meant to draw a line with each click of the mouse made within the figure. Here is my code;

```
b=1
while b>0;
    axis([-10, 10, -10, 10])
    b=b+1
    [x(b),y(b)]=ginput(1)  
    plot(x,y,x,y)
end
```

However I cant get my head around how I can add the vectors seeing as some are + and some are -, I need to turn the negatives into positives. I need to add code that will give me an overall combined length after all the mouse clicks. Maybe I am just thinking about it completely wrong.
I have tried;

```
length=(sqrt(x.^2)+(y.^2))
```

I was hoping this would give me the correct vector length accept unless I click an exact straight line.

Comment: You need to explain yourself better. can you take that 3 line paragraph and convert it to a step by step description of what you want to do?

Comment: this code as it is will go into an infinity loop, since the value of b is only ever getting bigger, i.e. b = b+1, and you are using the while loop, so b will always be greater than 0; I would be surprised if you didn't crash while running the code

Comment: Are you trying to get the sum of the length of each line?

Comment: Yeah just looking to get the sum at the moment. I know its an infinite look but I'm not suppressing the output so I can see what the code is doing. I have only posted what is working for me so far sorry.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help really new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is twofold: there's a typo, I think instead of

```
length=(sqrt(x.^2)+(y.^2))
```

you mean

```
length=sqrt((x.^2)+(y.^2))
```

The second problem is, that this does not actually calculate the length of your path, instead, you probably want something like

```
clear all
b=1;
radius = 3;
while b>0;
    axis([-10, 10, -10, 10])
    b=b+1;
    [x(b),y(b)]=ginput(1);  
    plot(x,y,x,y);
    length(b)=sqrt((x(b)-x(b-1))^2+(y(b)-y(b-1))^2);
    if sqrt(x(b)^2 + y(b)^2) < radius; break; end
end
sum(length)
```

which calculates the length for each new piece you add and sums them all up.
As soon as you click within "radius" distance of 0 the while loop breaks.
Also, generally it's good practice to preallocate variables, no big deal here, cause your arrays are small, just saying.

**Note:** Dan's solution gives you a vectorized way of calculating the total length in one step, so in case you don't need the individual path lengths this is the more concise way to go.

Comment: Sum length is the part I was looking for. I have to make the code end when I click back to zero.

Comment: You mean in the vicinity of zero? Cause it'll be hard to click precisely at (0,0)

Comment: See edit for leaving the loop if you are clicking anywhere within 'radius' of (0,0).

Comment: This is Perfect! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

So assuming that `x` and `y` are vectors of sequential points, if you want to get the total distance then you need to take the sum of the distance between each point i.e.

Σ<sub>i</sub>(sqrt((x<sub>i</sub>-x<sub>i-1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>+(y<sub>i</sub>-y<sub>i-1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>))

in Matlab we can calculate all the `x` (and `y`) differences in one step using the `diff` function so in the end we get

```
length = sum(sqrt(diff(x).^2 + diff(y).^2))
```